# SSIS - Maintain order of data from select statement columns

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SSIS package that is using a OLE DB Source component to select a list of columns from a SQL Server table. This data is then output to a flat file.

I have the columns in order of how I would like them to be output in the SELECT statement of the OLE component.

For example:

```
SELECT
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
from table;
```

However, when the OLE component maps and outputs them, it seems to do so in a random order. Is there anyway I can force the output to be in the order of how they are selected in the SQL statement?

Comment: In the flat file connection manager is where you control the order of the fields.  When the connection manager was created that was done, you should be able to change the order by editing the connection manager for the flat file.  The SQL order does not matter

Comment: @Brad Solid comment, make it an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flat file connection manager is where you control the order of the fields. When the connection manager was created that was done, you should be able to change the order by editing the connection manager for the flat file. The SQL order does not matter